# Android floating action button with custom background

Tags: android, material-design

Is it possible to set a custom background to a floating action button? For example, I'd like the fab to have background color with a gradient, and the "plus" icon on top of that. I've only seen simple background color so far. I'd like to keep using the design support library from Google.

Comment: DO not do that, please!

Answer (score 7):

You set background color to **Floating Action Button** through this property:

```
android:backgroundTint= "@color/colorPrimary"
```

and this does not accept `@drawable`. Which means you can not apply any drawable so my answer is **NO**, you cannot apply gradient to fab.

According to Google [Buttons: Floating Action Button](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button) documentation, Google suggests to avoid such designs.:

[image]

Comment: The FAB has a src, background and foreground attribute too. Here are some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720287/how-to-make-floating-action-button-background-gradient and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733369/how-to-set-the-background-of-a-fab-as-a-gradient

Answer (score 0):

Have a custom xml for the background and have a drawable for the src. With this you might be able to solve your problem. Hope this helps.