# How to make Floating Action Button background Gradient?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

**The code for FAB:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_chat"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The code for gradient background:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#e4849f"
    android:startColor="#d96e30" />
</shape>
```

android:backgroundTint="" or app:backgroundTint="" both uses color resources only.Can anyone suggest how to do this?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Step 1.** Create a new *drawable.xml* and add this code to it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <gradient
                    android:type="linear"
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:startColor="#f6ee19"
                    android:endColor="#115ede" />
            </shape>

        </item>
        <item android:gravity="center"
            >
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/your_icon"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

**Step 2**.) Now in your **dimens.xml** add this line of code,

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>
```

**Step 3.**) Finally set this drawable.xml in FAB using `*android:src="@drawable/drawable.xml"*`

P.S. - Make sure **your_icon** is a **PNG, JPEG**.

Comment: `<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen> 
` after adding above line streches the icon used as the `android:src="@drawable/your_icon"`

Comment: You need to set drawable which you created in the first step `android:src="@drawable/drawable.xml"` not `android:src="@drawable/your_icon"`

Comment: But this will override the complete app dimension also it seems like a hack. If there is not correct way we should mention that given solution is a *HACK*

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is working fine but after adding the below line, it stretches the icon added on **FAB**

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>
```

I am sharing the screenshots:

Previous **FAB button**

[image: previous **FAB button**]

After adding **design_fab_image_size** in dimen.xml and adding `android:src="@drawable/gradient"`, the icon get stretched:

[image: Stretched Fab button]

**To deal with this I replaced my gradient.xml with the following code**:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#00FF00"
            android:endColor="#000000" />
        <size
            android:width="56dp"
            android:height="56dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Output:

[image: fab_with_gradient]

Answer (score 3):

I tried a bunch of different answers but all had their shortcomings or didn't work with the `material FAB`.
When I realized this is *not what it is meant for* I simply replaced it with an `ImageView`. This works great and looks identical.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_gradient"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    ... />
```

fab_gradient.xml:

```
<ripple android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <gradient
                        android:type="linear"
                        android:angle="90"
                        android:startColor="@color/startColor"
                        android:endColor="@color/endColor" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_icon" android:gravity="center" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: This is was best worked for me. In fact, I didn't include the vector_icon item in the layer-list, since it looked stretched. I, instead, simply added it via the ImageButton android:src attribute. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="FullFABStyle">
    <item name="fabSize">normal</item>
    <item name="maxImageSize">@dimen/fab_size</item>
    <item name="fabCustomSize">@dimen/fab_size</item>
</style>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
    style="@style/FullFABStyle"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_background" />
```

So, yo do not need to override dimen

Answer (score 1):

This method works also. 
Create a shape called **fab_background.xml** in drawable where you can do all the customization you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="150dp" android:height="150dp"/>
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/colorAccentDark" android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

Create a layout called **custom_fab.xml** in layout then set the backround and fab icon using the image view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
    >

    <android.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can then reference it using `include`

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <include layout="@layout/custom_fab"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: [
                Color.fromRGBO(55, 59, 68, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(66, 134, 244, 1)
              ]),
        ),
        child: Icon(Icons.add)),
    onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
  ),
```

[Here is the image of the FloatingActionButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1ii9.png)

Comment: The given question related with Android Native which require either Java or Kotlin. Consider to give solution in Java or Kotlin. It seems you gave flutter's solution here, which isn't useful for native development.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CardView` instead with ripple effect:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
    app:cardElevation="12dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_gradient">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_svg"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The above answers are not working with SVGs and you might also see stretched icons etc. This is a neat way I used for my app according to material design for fab:

[image]

**Tip:** If it does not appear above the layer you want, play with the `elevation` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have this problem, the simple solution to achieve this is by setting the **foreground** of the **FAB**.

Like this example below:

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/circle_btn_gradient"
        />
```

Code for the drawable (circle_btn_gradient.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#2F8FC5"
                android:endColor="#1FCEB9"
                android:angle="270"
                />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
        android:top="15dp"
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```