# Looking for guidance on how to create these two Floating Action Button-looking buttons

Tags: android, material-design

I would like to create some buttons like you see in the picture (the small green + and red -) buttons. I have searched around for these buttons in the material design documents, but haven't found anything on these particular little buttons.

1. Are these just small FABs, or are they something different?
2. Does anybody know how to re-create these buttons if they are, or are
   not, FABs?

I took this screenshot from the default Samsung Contacts app in Oreo.

[image: Samsung default Contacts app in oreo]

Answer (score 1):

> Are these just small FABs, or are they something different?

You can say it can be small FABs using custom bacground, or it can be view using custom background

> Does anybody know how to re-create these buttons if they are, or are not, FABs?

In this case u can use imagebutton with custom background like this:

**1.** create new drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/gray22"
        android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

**2.** Finally add the custom background to your layout :

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/a_fab"
        android:src="@drawable/your_icon"/>
```

And if you want to use Fab u can try this :

**1.** Create new drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/gray22"
                android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

    <!-- for icon -->
    <item android:gravity="center" android:top="8dp" android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/your_icon
            android:gravity="center" />

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**2.** Add this code to ***dimens.xml***

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>
```

**3.** Finally add the custom backround to your layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a_fab"/>
```

Reference for using FAB [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49726387)